# Loading an HTML Form into my Android App via WebView?

Tags: java, android, html, forms

I am trying to load an HTML Form stored locally into my android app, fill out the fields, and capture the field names and data to a file or database.  Is using the WebView the right approach to doing this?

Thanks in advance!

RGecy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. WebView is the the right (and only way).

Answer (score 0):

Sure. http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html You can cooperate your app with js, and get the data you want.